# What are those ALSA Subdevices and what are they used for?

Tags: audio, pi-4, alsa

New to the community.

I was curious about one specific part from the ALSA driver on Raspberry Pi 4 (or even on other Linux machines using ALSA).

So `$ aplay -l` lists all current audio devices, but also their 'subdevices':

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Music $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 7/7
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 2: bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1 [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

As shown, card 0: device 0: has 7 subdevices.

So what are those 7 'subdevices' and what are their purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subdevices are for multiple audio services usage that would be mixed to input/output.

> There are also subdevices that are a part of an input or output
>   device. There must be at least 1 subdevice. In the context of output
>   devices, a device having multiple subdevices means the hardware can do
>   mixing, i.e. it can take multiple streams of PCM and mix them to
>   produce a single output. This's called hardware mixing and no,
>   multichannel is a different thing. The no. of streams a device can
>   take depends on the no. of sub devices a device has. Using ALSA API,
>   you can send audio to each of these subdevices simultaneously; the
>   result will be seen in the output audio.
>
> Subdevice in capturing means the card can take and digitize the input
>   of multiple audio streams at once. Usually, subdevice has 'modes' in
>   which they operate. For output subdevices, it means the multichannel
>   mode they operate in. Like 2 or 4 or 6 or 7 etc... which's activates
>   other multichannel ports on the sound card.

http://delogics.blogspot.com/2014/11/understanding-alsa-device-subdevice-and.html